# How can I add user's name in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, .net-core

I'm creating a UI App on C# using .NET Core .

I have to register users and let them login. So, the question is: how may I welcome logged user? I want the following: "Welcome back, {UserName}".

I create new window with input of class User object, so I know where to get his/her name, but I'm not sure how to program adding the name in .xaml.

Would be grateful for any possible help!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you may created a wpf Application(net core 3.0)?

When you logged from the log form. You can show the "Welcome back, {UserName}" in the main form.  Like the following simple code.

We can define a User object property in App class.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static Users usersd { get; set; }

}
```

And assign the User object when logging. Then, in the Main Windows/others form, you can show the user information:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.usersd != null)
        {
            label.Content = "Welcome back, {" + App.usersd.Name + "}";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to welcome users back, you need to store the user data in a database or in a file(.txt,.json,..). One way to do this is storing the user data as JSON when they first open the program. [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Then, you can check if the user has already logged in before. (perhaps use a userID property in User class)

Don't forget you need to add a NuGet package called Newtonsoft.Json in order to serialize and deserialize the data. [Install NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)